# Get an array of associations from an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of `Pictures`.  Each picture `has_many` comments.

If I have an array of pictures `@pictures`, how can I get all comments with a certain attribute from all pictures in `@pictures`?  Is there a nice Ruby one-liner for the following code?:

```
@comments = []
@pictures.each do |pic|
  pic.comments.each do |comment|
    if comment.text == "test"
      @comments << comment
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I know I can probably get this in one line from a database query, but I figure it would be more efficient to use the data that I already have, rather than re-query the database for ALL pictures, when I only care about a certain subset of pictures that I already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@comments =
@pictures
.flat_map(&:comments)
.select{|comment| comment.text == "test"}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` + `select` should do the trick:

```
@comments = @pictures.map(&:comments).flatten.select{|c| c.text == "test"}
```